# Convert String list to a dictionary

Tags: c#

I Have a string list like this `["saman=1", "kaman=2"]`
How may  I convert this to a dictionary like `{Saman:1 , kaman:2}`

```
strList.Select(k,v =>new {k,v} , k=> k.split('=')[0], val => v.split('=')[1]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
strList.ToDictionary(x => x.Split('=')[0], x => x.Split('=')[1])
```

If you want `Dictionary<string, int>` you can parse the `Value` to integer:

```
strList.ToDictionary(x => x.Split('=')[0], x => int.Parse(x.Split('=')[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should split by `", "` first, and then split each item by `=` to get key/value pairs.

Additional `Trim` call will get rid of `["` at the beginning and `"]` at the end of your input string.

```
var input = @"[""saman=1"", ""kaman=2""]";

var dict = input.Trim('[', '"', ']')
                .Split(new [] {@""", """}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(x => x.Split('='))
                .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Very, very simply with LINQ:

```
IDictionary<string, string> dictionary =
   list.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Note that this will fail if there are any duplicate keys - I assume that's okay?

Comment: this won't work.Because he has a `List<string>` not a `List<KeyValuePair>`